# Using NSMagnificationGestureRecognizer to zoom NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

What I am trying to achieve is simple gesture recognition to zoom in/out `ImageView` that I have in my `ScrollView`. I have done it by buttons pretty easily:

```
- (IBAction)zoomInAction:(id)sender {   
    if(scrollView.magnification < scrollView.maxMagnification) {
        scrollView.magnification = (scrollView.magnification + 0.1);
    }
}
```

Zoom out is the same just with subtraction of magnification.

How could I achieve the same result using `NSMagnificationGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: You don’t need to do anything except ensure `allowsMagnification` is set to YES . A pinch gesture will then magnify the contained `documentView`

Comment: In which part of program should I set it to YES? I have my scrollView outlet in `ViewController` class. Also it is a document-based app. (I have little experience in Obj-c)

Comment: Also in storyboard I have ticked box next to "Magnification Allow", but it doesn't seem to work in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ticking "Magnification Allow" box in storyboard's ViewController's ScrollView and **removing NSMagnificationGestureRecognizer** from ImageView seems to do the trick.